# AJAX POST request is failing because of Payload content length

Tags: java, json, ajax, tomcat, nginx

I am trying to consume REST service via ajax. For that I am sending jquery AJAX POST request which is failing with following message.

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"}
```

Payload size that we are trying to send is around 3 mb.

Service API is developed in JAVA and at service API side we have **nginx as Web server and tomcat as application server.**

How can I increase payload content length so that we can have resolution to above error?

AJAX is as below:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
          // Headers as below
          setRequestHeadersOfFMAPI(request);
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: (3000 * 60 * 10),
        url: urlContext + "/api/v1/application/google_bps_app/metrics/actuals",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "actuals": activities
        }),

        success: function (data) {

        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit Tomcat's `server.xml`. In the `<Connector>` element, add an attribute `maxPostSize` and set a larger value (in bytes) to increase the limit.

Comment: Sorry but we are using Java. Edited my question to add that.

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the packet size you don't need to do anything on Java side but you need to change the nginx configuration on server.

You need to increase the size (which might be set in configuration, if not add it) for the parameter, `client_max_body_size`.

**Remember** This parameter takes size in bytes, so calculate and put the number as high as your packet max size may be.

Comment: do i need to add it as client_max_body_size in nginx.conf as a variable?

Comment: In server section which is defined to handle your http port traffic, for example `server { client_max_body_size 4194304; }`

Comment: changed this but it is not resolving problem

Comment: did you restart the nginx after saving the script because the same work at our side perfectly, If you have php installed then, the link may be helpful http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/